# C# Sqlparameter add

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sqlparameter

i have a class for my sql duety, and have problem for my 
how could i do something like this

```
SqlParameter storedparam = new SqlParameter();
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@userid", SqlDbType.BigInt);
param1.Value = "87";
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@ip",SqlDbType.VarChar,40);
param2.Value = "192.168.1.1";
storedparam = param1 + param2;  //this parth have problem
Db myobject = new Db(myconection);
myobject.writestoredpro("nameofsotred",storedparam )
```

Comment: What is the parameter that your query expects?

Comment: Without knowing what type of API `writestoredpro` is expecting, that is pretty much impossible to answer, What is `writestoredpro` ? And what is `Db` ?

Comment: something like my simple example code

Comment: You are multiple `BigInt` and `VarChar` ?

Comment: @Mahyar your "simple example code" does nothing to explain what `writestoredpro` wants...

Comment: Just saying... `myconection.Execute("nameofsotred", new {userid = 87, ip = "192.168.1.1"}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);` (via ["dapper"](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper))

Comment: writestoredpro is and method for my Db class that get stored procedure named and its parameter for executing,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sql duety, take in params `SqlParameter[]` like so:

```
public void WriteStoredProcedure( string Query, params SqlParameter[] SqlParameters ) {
    // do it
}
```

For cases where you're defining a parameter and want to run it in one go, you can also define it like so:

```
SqlParameter storedParam = new SqlParameter("@ip",SqlDbType.Varchar,40) {
    Value = "192.168.1.1"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the 'writetostoredpro' method would need to take a collection of SqlParameter objects, and then inside the method, you would need to iterate over the collection adding them to the SqlCommand.Parameters property.  Take a look at this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx of how to use the propertied, and SqlCommand class for an idea of what to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4956bkc.aspx